# UIAutomation logElementTree() returns UIAElementNil

Tags: instruments, ui-automation, xcode-instruments

When us this line of code to logElementTree() in Instruments UIAutomation  `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().logElementTree();`

The results return is `UIAElementNil`

Even when I record a script and tap on the screen the only line that gets recorded is `target.frontMostApp().tap();`

Comment: Have you had any fortune with this...

Answer (score 2):

you might have enabled accessibility for the main view.
if your provide the accessibility label for the main view then you will not get accessibility label for the child. try removing accessibility for the main view, you will get full hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `isAccessibilityElement = YES`. If you do then the subviews of that element are hidden.

You should set `accessibilityItentifier = @"xxxx"; isAccessibilityElement = NO;`

Comment: Don't set on what? The application window?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use "target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().logElementTree();", instead use "target.logElementTree()" always. It will display all the elements present on the current screen.

Comment: That doesn't work it now only logs the name of the app 'UIAApplication: name:MyApp rect:{{1024, 0}, {0, 0}}' and I cant drill down in the hierarchy

Comment: Could you please tell that why you are not able to drill down hierarchy? And if its the only thing you are able to see under that, just add delay before the desired screen appears and then do 'target.logElementTree()'. Try this, hope it will work for you or revert back with some details specifically.

Comment: There is no arrow next to the UIALogger results to drill down into

Comment: Add delay before `target.logElementTree()` get executed on desired screen, ensure that delay is sufficient so that desired screen appears first and then `target.logElementTree()` executes.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().logElementTree();`
Instead of your code replace it with this:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
target.logElementTree();
```